# question on CTMC vs DTMC (markov chain)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I studied that if continuous time markov chain (CTMC) (let say $X(t)$ has a rate matrix $Q$, its time step $t$ transition probability is $P=exp(tQ)$.

So question here is that does this imply its sampled process every time $t$, (say $X_n$) is also a Markov chain? Is it obvious fact? How can we argue (or prove) it?

Comment: Is the sampled process $X_n = X(T_0 + nT)$ for fixed $T_0, T>0$?  If so, it should follow directly from the definitions of CTMC and DTMC (without regard for whether the rate matrix and transition matrix are related as you've stated)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I also "believe" it is true, but what makes me confused is this: suppose transition 0->1. case 1) transition occurs at nT+epsilon, 2) transition occurs at (n+1)T-epsilon.
Those two events reduce to the same DTMC, but transition probability P are the same for 1) and 2)?

Comment: I can't follow your question.  Using my definition of $X_n$, are you just setting $T_0 = \epsilon$ and $T_0 = 1-\epsilon$ respectively?  If so, then if $X(t)$ is time-homogeneous (which I guess is the context, if $Q$ doesn't depend on $t$?), then yes, the resulting DTMC will be time-homogeneous with a transition matrix that doesn't depend on $T_0$ (though the initial distribution $X_0$ will)

Comment: Sorry Brian, my bad. consider two realizations of $X(t)$ and let $T_0=0$. 1) transition occurs at $nT+\epsilon$, 2) transition occurs at $(n+1)T-\epsilon$. and no changes till $(n+1)T$. Then both realizations give the same DTMC $X_n$ realizations, right? But can we say $P(X_{n+2}|X_{n+1})$ are identical in both cases?

Comment: How are you defining transition probabilities on the level of realizations?  If $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$ is such that $$X(t)(\omega_1) = \begin{cases}0 & nT \leq t < nT+\epsilon \\  1 & nT+\epsilon \leq t \leq (n+1)T\end{cases} \\ X(t)(\omega_2) = \begin{cases}0 & nT \leq t < (n+1)T-\epsilon \\  1 & (n+1)T-\epsilon \leq t \leq (n+1)T\end{cases}$$
then both $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are in the event we are measuring when we compute $P(X_{n+1}=1 | X_n = 0)$.  The realizations themselves aren't assigned transition probabilities; they are what are measured to define transition probabilities.